# Understanding of regmap_add_irq_chip function

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

In one of the drivers which is already present in our SDK they are by default calling regmap_add_irq_chip function. We had tried understanding the function but found it difficult to understand it. Can anyone please explain what is happening in that function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's defined and documented in `drivers/base/regmap/regmap-irq.c` in Linux kernel tree. What part don't you understand?

Comment: From our understanding first the chip's interrupt status registers will be read and after that acknowledgement will be given. What we can't understand is like from where it is taking the register values and what will happens if the chip has no interrupt write registers?

Comment: Answer to the comment: `_add_irq_chip()` means that the chip provides the IRQ chip functionality and we drive it in the software. Your second question make no sense.